# Conditional sentence for specific rows

Tags: r

Disclaimer: I am not that advanced with R Studio and hence my question might be quite self explanatory.

Lets assume the following data set

```
**ID value1a value2a value1b value2b ...
  1  2       3       ...
  8  4       4
  2  5       5
```

I want to create a forth variable that is part of the expression of an if sentence, that logically should go as follows:

If ID = 1 is over 5 in "value1x" and below 3 in "value2x", then add the value 1 to this forth variable. Hence the forth variable should function as a counter, that the number in the forth variable indiciates the frequency of value1x being over 5 and value2x being below 3.

I hope my question makes sense and Id appreciate answers!

Comment: `df$col4 <- +(df$value1a > 5 & df$value2x < 3)`. Typically the parenthetic portion will return `TRUE` or `FALSE`, but the leading `+` is a shortcut for coercing to an `integer`. (Cf, `+T` and `+F`.)

Comment: Thank you so much! This worked for me!